# Introducing API key in reverse method (geocoder python library)

Tags: python-3.x, reverse, geocoder

I would appreciate some help with this: I am trying to get county and country given a geolocalization using reverse method of geocoder python library. It asks me to include an API key, once I get the token/key from my account in mapbox, how could I add it to my query?

```
import geocoder

g = geocoder.mapbox([53.3887213, -2.732602113], method='reverse')
print(g.county)
print(g.country)
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: In case useful for someone:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
import geocoder

latlng = [45.3, -105.1]
g = geocoder.mapbox(latlng, 
                    key='ACCESS_MAPBOX_TOKEN', 
                    method='reverse')
g.json
```